# How to put content elements side-by-side int typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content

I have just started my `Typo3` journey. I want to put 2 `content elements` side-by-side (in one row). Can anyone tell how is it possible. Because whenever I place any `content element`, it is displayed as a block and fill the entire `row`.
**Thank you for your time and consideration :)**

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in solution for your problem.

But in TYPO3 you are free to build any kind of html structure for your output. This is necessary as you also can do any rendering of content. either with your own CSS and HTML-markup or if you use frameworks like Bootstrap.

You can build a new page layout, or any special content element which contains other content elements.

Changing layouts can (and should) be reflected in backend-layouts.  (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Backend/BackendLayout.html) (there are a lot of other tutorials)

But you also can build/ use individual defined containing content elements. Her you can get support by different extensions (eg. mask, DCE, gridelements) or define it completely on your own (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use container elements which come with the extension 'container'. Please have a look at https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/container